# how to delete rows NOT containing #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I have an autofill for a vlookup and I want to remove/delete all rows that ARE NOT #N/A in column E (I want to keep only the rows that generate an error)

I have a code that does the opposite and deletes all rows that CONTAIN #N/A, but I need to opposite

```
On Error Resume Next
Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Look at the questions under "Related" over to the right of this page.

Comment: not sure I'm seeing the same "Related" as you. #N/A is not a text or a string, so I'm having trouble deleting all but the #N/A

Comment: You can use `application.worksheetfunction.isna(cellValue)` to test if a cell is #NA - otherwise the related questions cover the general process.

Comment: Hide the error rows and delete the visible rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "xlErrors" you can use **xlTextValues** or **xlNumbers**
like this:

```
Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlTextValues).EntireRow.Delete
```

or

```
Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlNumbers).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple change and it worked..worked great! :)